# How to change database property derby.database.sqlAuthorization to 'TRUE'

Tags: php, derby, netbeans-8

I try to execute this command:

```
GRANT ALL ON demo.* TO 'username'@'localhost';
```

But get this error:

```
Error code 30000, SQL state 42Z60: GRANT not allowed unless database property derby.database.sqlAuthorization has value 'TRUE'.
```

Any idea how to change the property to true??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is lots of information about this topic in this manual: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/security/

Specifically, you'll want to focus on this section: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/security/csecauthorization.html